# Aggregating values in groups of irregular length using a stop values

Tags: r, grouping

I'm trying to create groups of values using keywords that have been manually entered. for example if I have a rollcall sheet with values that can be produced with the following code

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Fred", "Victoria", "Jim", "Sally", "Ted", "Pamela", "end", "Victoria", "Fred", "Sally", "end", "Sally", "Pamela"), 
                 sex = c("man", "woman", "man", "woman", "man", "woman", "neither", "woman", "man", "woman", "neither", "woman", "woman"))
```

Is it possible to group these values into days such that I have three days, arranged so that one could ask the question, "On what day(s), was Sally present with a man" ?

Comment: You have a lot of possible combinations, what would your output look like? Or can you give an example of a possible day+name+sex?

Comment: Both of these answers work perfectly! I wish I could select both as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create day with `cumsum`:

```
df$day <- cumsum(df$name == 'end')
df <- df[df$day != 'end', ]
unique(df$day[df$sex == 'man' & df$day %in% df$day[df$name == 'Sally']])
# [1] 0 1
```

So,  "On first two day(s), Sally was present with a man".

---

edit: I mistook the question at first. The error has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This may require two parts and use the `dplyr` package:

```
df.1 <- df %>% 
        mutate(day = cumsum(name == "end")) %>% 
        group_by(day) %>% 
        summarise(man = any(sex == "man"), woman = any(sex == "female"))

df   <- df %>%
        mutate(day = cumsum(name == "end")) %>%
        left_join(df.1, by = "day")
```

From here you can now search seeing as you have a `day` column, and if `man` was present on that day column, and if `woman` was present on that day. To determine the answer to your question you can simply search using

```
df$day[which(df$name == "Sally" & df$man == TRUE)]
```

which results in

```
[1] 0 1
```

This method creates a table for you to search along these components.